# Why isn't cp --preserve=ownership working?

Tags: linux, cp

I have a directory "foo" owned by `myusername` which contains a directory "bar" owned by `www-data`.

If I run this command

```
cp --preserve=ownership -r foo/ /tmp/
```

Then the created directory `/tmp/foo/bar` is owned by `myusername` and not by `www-data`.

Why not? Isn't this exactly what `-preserve=ownership` is supposed to do?

Happening under Ubuntu/zsh.

Comment: This is off-topic here.

Comment: Only root can change the username of the copied files, if the `cp` is ran without root, the original username of the executor is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only root is allowed to create files that are owned by someone other than itself. So, to make it work, run the command as root.

If you *are* running it as root, I suppose the filesystem you are copying the file to maps all files to one user (for instance, filesystems that don't support file ownership can be mounted in such a way)